# Swift make a phone call from the WebView

Tags: swift, ios8, ios-web-app

I'm trying to make a call from click on `WebView` but not work.

```
func webView(webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: NSURLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {

    if navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationType.LinkClicked {

        if (request.URL?.absoluteString!.rangeOfString("tel://") != nil) {

            var phone : String = request.URL!.absoluteString!

            println(phone)

            var url:NSURL? = NSURL(string: phone)
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url!)

            return false

        } else {

            return true

        }
    }

    return true
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is untested but I think you could do something like:

```
func webView(webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: NSURLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {
    if navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationType.LinkClicked {
        let application = UIApplication.sharedApplication()
        if let phoneURL = request.URL where (phoneURL.absoluteString!.rangeOfString("tel://") != nil) {
            if application.canOpenURL(phoneURL) {
                application.openURL(phoneURL)
                return false
            }
        }
    } 
    return true
}
```

You should note that this will not work on the Simulator as `application.canOpenURL(phoneURL)` will return `false`. This will only work on an actual iPhone.

Comment: Thanks, I was testing in the emulator, as I was stupid!